# CSS Computed styles not matching what shows in browser

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

This is a picture of my dev tools computed styles. I have my CSS set to make the link white, and text-decoration on none.

Why would it show everything crossed out, except for white, and then end up being computed as rgb(102, 102, 102)? Very confused.

[image]

Comment: Learn about what the "cascade" actually is in C(ascading)SS and its most notable feature, selector precedence - it should help make sense of why some of your properties are being beaten by others.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well (oddly, it was the same exact color that was incorrectly overriding for me!) I was similarly very confused as the Chrome Inspector was clearly showing that one style was beating out the others....except....it wasn't.

It is likely a pseudo-class being applied, which is not always super clear in the Computed tab. For me, it was the `:visited` pseudo-class that was applying the dark grey over my lighter grey that was being showing as the primary styling.